# How to echo values from 2 different tables?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have 2 tables and I would want to echo values from this 2 tables.

**Schedule table**

[image]

**Scheduletime table**

[image]

This is my code,

```html
<?php
    if (!mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
        $sqlQueryStr = "SELECT * FROM scheduletime ST, schedule S WHERE ST.schedule_Id = S.schedule_Id AND ST.staff_Id= $id  AND ST.Monday= '1' ";

        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sqlQueryStr);

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $button[$row['scheduleTime_Id']] = $row;
        }

        mysqli_close($con);
    } else {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

foreach ($button as $id => $info) {
    echo $id;
    echo $info['startTime']; //startTime is from scheduletime table
    echo $info['endTime']; //endTime is from scheduletime table
    echo $info['academicInstitution']; //academicInstitution is from schedule table
    echo '</br>';
}
```

I am able to echo out the values from "scheduletime" but not from "schedule". How to echo values from 2 different tables?

Comment: `SELECT S.*, ST.* FROM scheduletime ST, schedule S ...`

Comment: exactly as you're doing. probably your query isn't constructed properly, so `var_dump($button)` to see what you really got. you'll probably find you ARE getting `academicInstitution` data in there, but it's all `null`

Comment: @developerwjk thanks for the reminder, i forgot about that. :D